# [Error]The shelveset _Build_15980;Build\c868874f-b02b-4b5e-83a4-b73f73940386 could not be found for check-in

Tags: azure-devops

Getting error  "[Error]The shelveset _Build_15980;Build\c868874f-b02b-4b5e-83a4-b73f73940386 could not be found for check-in" while trying to check-in from Visual Studio for VSTS for Gated check-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to disabled '`limit job authorization scope to current project`'. For details, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#job-authorization-scope).

Basically having this enabled reduces the permission scope of the pipeline to the resources within a project. By disabling it, a pipeline can run with collection scoped access which reaches outside of the project that the pipeline is in.

In project settings:

[image]

In organization settings:

[image]

You can refer to this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/gated-check-in-error-could-not-found-the-shelveset/812664) with the same issue.